# How to get list of subscribed queue names in Celery/Django?

Tags: python, django, celery

My worker is run with:

`celery worker -A workerTasks -n Worker%h --concurrency=1 --loglevel=info -Q $QUEUE_NAME -f $WORKER_LOG_FILE --pidfile=/logs/worker_pid%h.pid`

I'm wondering if I can make a python/celery call within the process to find which queue(s) this worker is "subscribed" to?

(I do NOT want to find the value of $QUEUE_NAME directly)

Answer (score 0):

`celery -A workerTasks inspect active_queues -d <worker name>`, where `worker name` is the name of that particular node. If you omit `-w <worker name>` each node will send you report about which queue it is subscribed to.